# How to write python tornado test to assert the ioloop has shutdown?

Tags: python, tornado, python-asyncio, application-shutdown

I have some code that will intercept SIGTERM/SIGINT and will instruct the tornado ioloop (which is a wrapper around the asyncio loop) to wait for inflight requests to complete before shutting the tornado ioloop down (see below).

```
"""signals module provides helper functions for tornado graceful shutdown."""

import asyncio
import functools
import signal
import time

from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT = 30


def sig_handler(server: HTTPServer, timeout: int, sig, frame):
    """Schedules ioloop shutdown after specified timeout when TERM/INT signals received.

    In-flights tasks running on the asyncio event loop will be given the
    opportunity to finish before the loop is shutdown after specified timeout.

    Expects to be initiated using partial application:
        functools.partial(sig_handler, HTTPServer())
    This partial application is typically handled by signals.sig_listener.
    """

    io_loop = IOLoop.current()

    def stop_loop(deadline):
        now = time.time()
        tasks = asyncio.all_tasks()

        if now < deadline and len(tasks) > 0:
            # defer shutdown until all tasks have a chance to complete
            io_loop.add_timeout(now + 1, stop_loop, deadline)
        else:
            io_loop.stop()

    async def shutdown():
        # stop listening for new connections
        server.stop()

        # schedule ioloop shutdown
        stop_loop(time.time() + timeout)

    # execute callback on next event loop tick
    io_loop.add_callback_from_signal(shutdown)


def sig_listener(server: HTTPServer, timeout: int = 0):
    """Configures listeners for TERM/INT signals.

    Timeout should be a positive integer, otherwise a default will be provided.
    """

    if not timeout:
        timeout = SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT

    p = functools.partial(sig_handler, server, timeout)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, p)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, p)
```

This code (see above) works fine and I've manually tested it does what we need, but I have no idea how to achieve the same thing in an automated test using `AsyncHTTPTestCase` as that makes async requests synchronous + the ioloop we’re trying to shutdown is the same one that the test itself is going to be running on.

The following code is what I have currently...

```py
import asyncio
import os
import signal
import threading
import time

import bf_metrics

import bf_tornado.handlers
import bf_tornado.signals

import tornado.gen
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.testing
import tornado.web


class TestGracefulShutdown(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
    def get_app(self):
        class FooHandler(bf_tornado.handlers.BaseHandler):
            metrics = bf_metrics.Metrics(namespace='foo', host='localhost')

            def get(self):
                asyncio.sleep(5)
                self.finish('OK')

        return tornado.web.Application([
            (r'/', FooHandler)
        ])

    def test_graceful_shutdown(self):
        # override AsyncHTTPTestCase default timeout of 5s
        os.environ["ASYNC_TEST_TIMEOUT"] = "10"

        shutdown_timeout = 8
        bf_tornado.signals.sig_listener(self.http_server, shutdown_timeout)

        pid = os.getpid()

        def trigger_signal():
            # defer SIGNINT long enough to allow HTTP request to tornado server
            time.sleep(2)
            os.kill(pid, signal.SIGINT)

        thread = threading.Thread(target=trigger_signal)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

        resp = self.fetch('/')
        assert resp.code == 200

        # ???
        #
        # WHAT ASSERTION DO WE USE HERE?
        #
        # WE CAN'T CHECK tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current()
        # BECAUSE IT'LL STILL BE RUNNING AS PART OF THIS TEST.
        #
        # MAYBE WE COULD TEST asyncio.all_tasks() ? BUT WE WANT TO BE ABLE TO
        # SAY CONCLUSIVELY THAT THE IOLOOP WAS SHUTDOWN.
        #
        # ???
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is something you can test with AsyncHTTPTestCase, because the starting and stopping of the event loop is hidden from you (If you don't use `@gen_test`, the IOLoop is already stopped most of the time. If you do use `@gen_test`, there is an IOLoop that's always running, but if you stop it your test will just hang).  In order to test that the IOLoop stops, your code needs to be the thing that calls `IOLoop.start()`.

The most comprehensive way to test this kind of startup and shutdown issue is to run your server as a subprocess. This way you can send it both HTTP requests and signals, and see that the process exits.

There are also ways to do this in the current process, with various tradeoffs between realism and performance. For example, something like this:

```
def test_graceful_shutdown(self):
    def trigger_signal():
        time.sleep(2)
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=trigger_signal)
    thread.start()

    io_loop = IOLoop()
    install_signal_handler(io_loop)
    def failure():
        self.fail("did not shut down within 5 seconds")
        io_loop.stop()
    io_loop.call_after(5, failure)
    io_loop.start()
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback Ben. I did manage to test this, although required a _little_ funky usage of the unittest.TestCase tearDown function: https://gist.github.com/Integralist/53e926c454e34cb76445c228ded41e95#file-4-working-example-python-3-7-tornado-5-example-with-tests-md